# Trying to get a LAMP configuration with PHP7 on a Jessie server

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, lamp

I'm trying to configure my new server with a Jessie installation able to run a full LAMP environment, with phpmyadmin.

**Apache, MySQL, PHP**
I installed apache2 and mysql with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql
```

Then I installed PHP7 as instructed here : https://www.dotdeb.org/2016/01/08/php-7-0-2-for-jessie/

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

> deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
>   deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php-mysql
```

Which installed, among other things, php7 packages for mysql : php7.0-mysql php-mysql

**PhpMyAdmin**
Now I have trouble with phpmyadmin.
As found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpmyadmin-with-php7), I cloned the phpmyadmin git :

```
cd /var/www/phpmyadmin
git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git
mkdir logs
```

Then I made a vhost for it.

```
nano /etc/apache2/phpmyadmin.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
     ServerName phpmyadmin.url
     DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin/
     ErrorLog /var/www/phpmyadmin/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/phpmyadmin/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

--end of "all is going well" part--

**The problem**
Trying to reach phpmyadmin ends with the message :

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See our documentation for more information.

I found in the php.ini (located /etc/php/7.0/apache2) the line for Windows extension "extension=php_mysqli.dll" commented, but obviously, uncommenting it didn't change anything.

I'm stuck here, I can't find information about installing mysqli with php7.
Is it impossible at the moment ?
Is there a way to tell phpmyadmin to use another way (if there is any) ?

I remember I had to install a lot of packages when runnning php5 environment, and I was surprised it was alot easier with php7. I guess lot of packages are missing now.
Any recommendation / suggestion is welcome.

(I'll complete the "all is going well" part with more instructions as I find them)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Could you expose your solution, please!

Comment: What solution ? Which part do you want me to expose ?  
Unless I misunderstood your question (english is not my native language), I don't have a working environment yet, so, no solution so far.

Comment: My mistake. I not understood your question. I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure your Apache instance is using the same version of PHP as the one you installed? Check `phpinfo();` and see if MySQLi is there

Comment: So, you installed PHP like that ?

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install php7.0`
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: T'lash : I installed php by adding the dotdeb repo in the sources.list and the update and install php7.0 (I edited my post to include that).

Andrea : thanks for the idea, I forgot such basic check. Mysqli is indeed installed. And huh when I checked today, PMA worked. I messed with the PMA setup yesterday, didn't think it would do anything. I'll answer my own question, will help anyone in the same situation, like Martin

Comment: @Martin can you do the steps I detailed in my answer, and confirm this is the solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: If you put the downloaded files in `/var/www/`, which is already shared as the web root, why create a vhost for it also?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I don't want to be able to access every sub folder with myserveradress/subdirectory, I prefer to make a vhost for each, so I choose what is accessible from Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli was correctly installed (visible in the phpinfo() data). The problem was from PhpMyAdmin. I tried to setup PMA like this :

```
cd /var/www/phpmyadmin
sudo mkdir config
sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config/config.inc.php
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data config/
chmod -R 655 config/
```

It's maybe not optimized but I'm just pasting my bash history, I was in the state "I'm not sure what I'm doing, let's try this".

Then I launched PMA with the setup suffix  : pmaurl.ext/setup
I don't think I modified anything, but right after I forgot to check if PMA worked.
Today it does, and asked me to remove the config directory.

Yay ! Problem solved !

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. I'm glad it works for you now, but in this sequence of steps you didn't do anything that would change how phpMyAdmin works. The config directory isn't used by phpMyAdmin itself, only the setup script which can help create or modify a `config.inc.php` -- which you then need to manually move for phpMyAdmin to use (as a security feature). Furthermore, that has no effect on the PHP configuration anyway -- so while I'm truly happy that it works for you now, I'm pretty sure the solution was something independent of these steps.

Comment: I know that doesn't make much sense. I almost came to think that the error message from PMA was inappropriate and a result of something that didn't behave like usual because of the PHP7 environment. I also thought that the setup process fixed something that caused the error, hence the removal of config directory requested right after. That's pure speculation though.

Comment: I'll definitely keep an eye out for similar issues in the future! Thanks.